# Why does my picture look kinda blurry on Instagram?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Kinda of a help from all of you guys. I’m not a graphic designer but I was hoping someone can help me out with a photo?

The photo looks great but as soon as I set it as my Instagram profile picture, it becomes blurry and kinda awful . I have tried different formats but it comes out the same every single time.

Hopefully someone can help me out please

I've attached the png and also a screen shot of how it looks on Instagram
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/96qnS.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kefIc.jpg)

Comment: did you notice that your original image is almost 3x larger?

Comment: Is there anyway you can personally help me out? Like tell me what to do? What steps I should take?

Comment: Check the duplicate question, there are plenty answers there. But essentially, resize down your image and stop zooming in so much, the instagram profile image IS small and will look blurry if you zoom in.

Comment: What does zooming in mean? I’ve tried to readjust the image to a square and revise the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This picture is way too large with 3024px width and height. That's about 1 meter x 1 meter big with a resolution of 72 dpi. Instagram compresses too large images. And with your picture it has a lot of resizing and compressing to do and the online engine is not the best to do that. The minimum size is 110 x 110 px. So try maybe resizing it yourself to 180 x 180px.

Here's some further reading material: https://codeless.co/instagram-profile-picture-size/

Comment: Instead of an online engine, what should I use? Any apps or websites that you recommend me on going to fixing the image?

Comment: Well I would use photoshop but that's a bit too bigg an investment for just needing to resize images (Although I'm sure the free tool gimp can resize images just fine as well). But there are several websites dedicated to resizing them. Such as https://www.reduceimages.com/ But since you probably want to do that on your Smartphone, there are also apps like Reduce Photo Size App (I never tried any of them though). Anyway for finding the right application for your use, google is your friend ;)